# Does vomiting breaks one's fast?

Tags: sawm

Does our fast is effected by vomiting.Because some people says that our fast is not effected by vomit.But some people says that it is.So, I am confused about this. Anyone can guide.

Answer (score 3):

Vomiting can be either induced voluntarily or occur involuntarily. The latter one does not break the fast:

> قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ من ذرعه القيء فلا قضاء عليه ومن استقاء فعليه القضاء
>
> Whoever is overcome and vomits is not to make up for the day (of fasting), but whoever vomits intentionally must make up the day.
>
> <sup>— [Narrated by Abu Daud, Nasai, Tirmidhi, Ibn Majah and Ahmad etc.](https://sunnah.com/urn/2059210)</sup>

Also returning or ingesting the vomit breaks the fast if done intentionally, or even unintentionally according to some views.

References:

- [الهداية في شرح بداية المبتدي](https://al-maktaba.org/book/11820/165#p1) ([English Translation](https://archive.org/details/Hedaya_201703/page/n197))
- [Jurisprudence according to the four schools](https://archive.org/stream/IslamicJurisprudenceAccordingToTheFourSunniSchoolsAlFiqhalaAlMadhahibAlArbaah#page/n787/mode/2up/search/vomit)
- [الموسوعة الفقهية](https://archive.org/stream/FPmfkmfk/mfk28#page/n66/mode/2up)

Answer (score -1):

Al-Bukhaari and Muslim narrated that Abu Hurayrah said: The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever forgets he is fasting and eats or drinks, let him complete his fast for it is Allaah Who has fed him and given him to drink.”

Al-Daaraqutni narrated from Abu Sa’eed al-Khudri that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever eats in the month of Ramadaan by mistake does not have to make up that day.”

So if even eating by mistake does not break one's fast, how can vomiting break it which you have no control over.

Comment: People can induce vomiting. Does your ruling still apply in that case?

Comment: @goldPseudo  no, it does not cover that case.  but vomiting is not eating nor drinking, so it cannot break fasting. even if bits of vomit is swallowed while vomiting, it does not matter because it's going back where it was anyways.

Answer (score -2):

you have no control on vomit so i think vomit doesn't break the fast.